# How to prove this series: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}\ln n}{n}=\gamma \ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\ln^22$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

How to prove this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}\ln n}{n}=\gamma \ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\ln^22$$
and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}\ln \left ( n+1 \right )}{n+1}&=\frac{1}{2}\ln^22-\gamma \ln 2\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}\ln \left ( n+2 \right )}{n+2}&=\gamma \ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\ln^22-\frac{1}{2}\ln 2
\end{align*}
So I want to know, is there a closed form for

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}\ln \left ( n+k \right )}{n+k}~~~\left ( k>0 \right )$$

Comment: Final question: "no different" = "first $k$ terms omitted".  Final question can be asked for $k$ not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, for any $\alpha>1$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\alpha} = (2^{1-\alpha}-1)\cdot\zeta(\alpha) \tag{1}$$
hence the main result (or the secondary one up to a shift of the summation variable) follows from considering the opposite of the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ of both sides, followed by an evaluation of the limit for $\alpha\to 1^+$.

Comment: I tried,but I don't know how to evaluate the limit?Could you please give me some hints or make an answer using it. Thank you.